# Menu item riding up the page

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have a menu item that rides up the page on some devices. Mostly it's fine but sometimes the top item, `drawing Development` goes higher than the other items.

This is the css applied.

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) 
 {.dropdown 
 {transform:rotate(270deg); 
 left: -25px;}}
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="collapse 
navbar-collapse navbar-ex1- 
collapse"><ul id="menu" 
class="menu"><li id="menu- 
item-3530" class="menu-item 
menu-item-type-post_type 
menu-item-object-page menu- 
item-has-children menu- 
item-3530 dropdown"><a 
title="Contact"  
href="https://4309.co.uk
/contact/">Contact 
<ul role="menu" class=" 
dropdown-menu">
<li id="menu-item-12515" 
class="menu-item menu-item- 
type-post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item- 
12515"><a title="DRAWING 
DEVELOPMENT"  
href="https://4309.co.uk/dr
awing-development/">DRAWING 
DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2997" 
class="menu-item menu-item- 
type-post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item- 
2997"><a title="SKETCHES"  
href="https://4309. 
co.uk/sketches-life- 
drawing/">SKETCHES</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3529" 
class="menu-item menu-item- 
type-post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item- 
3529"><a title="LOGOS"  
href="https://4309.
co.uk/logos/">LOGOS</a>. 
</li>
<li id="menu-item-3531" 
class="menu-item menu-item- 
type-post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item- 
3531"><a title="DRAWING" 
href="https://4309.co
.uk/portraits/">DRAWING</a> 
</li>
<li id="menu-item-3751" 
class="menu-item menu-item- 
type-post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item- 
3751"><a title="ABOUT US"  
href="https://4309.co.uk
/about-us/">ABOUT US</a>. 
</li>
```

So how do i get all items to sit on the same line? I tried altering height (as it's rotated) but same problem occurred.

[here](https://4309.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<li id="menu-item-12515" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12515">
  <a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/" data-slimstat="5"></a>
  <a title="DRAWING DEVELOPMENT" href="https://4309.co.uk/drawing-development/" data-slimstat="5">DRAWING DEVELOPMENT</a>
</li>
```

You need to remove the invisible Contact element or put it as dedicated li-item.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that? I'd need to edit my php i think but not sure how....

Comment: You need to provide the PHP-Code then, otherwise i cant help you.

Comment: Where would i find php for menu? In header.php and navwalker.php i have things like `wp_nav-menu` i think, but not sure what's outputting individual menu items...